# java linked list

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am working on a linked list problem, here is the question problem with my code, I am having three errors, please help.

Write a function called "odd" that takes a linked list and returns the odd-numbered elements. Actually, write two functions called "odd" and "even". odd(L) returns a list of the 1st,3rd,5th... items in L. even(L) returns a list of the 2nd,4th,6th... items in L. And each function calls the other. These two functions are based on a simple observation. L.next is like L, but with the first item missing. If we take away the first item, item N+1 becomes item N. So the 2nd,3rd,4th elements of L are the 1st,2nd,3rd elements of L.next. Now if N+1 is odd, N is even, while if N+1 is even N is odd. So the odd members of L.next are even members of L, and the even members of L.next are odd members of L. Then we can compute odd(L) as follows. If L is null return null. Otherwise return a list whose first item is L.item, while its tail is even(L.next). To compute even(L): If L is null return null. Otherwise return odd(L.next). Your main function should read a list of positive integers from the command line, with -1 terminating the list. It should form a linked list containing these integers, compute the list of odd members, and print them.

my code:

```
public class linkedlist
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  List odd = new ArrayList();
  List even = new ArrayList();
  odd(L, odd, even);
}
void odd(L curNode, ArrayList oddList, ArrayList evenList) 
{

   if (curNode == null) return;


   oddList.append(curNode.val);
   even(curNode, oddList, evenList);
}

void even(L curNode, ArrayList oddList, ArrayList evenList) 
{
   if (curNode == null || curNode.next == null) return;


   evenList.append(curNode.n ext.val);
   odd(curNode.next.next, oddList, evenList);
}
}
```

Comment: @MatinKh homework tag is obsolete since recently...

Comment: hi, it is homework, but I have worked on it but still getting errors, I do not want anyone to write me the code, I just need a hint on my errors. Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: @MeredithAhlberg I you supposed to create a Linked List separate from any Java Library lists  - or use one of the Java pre-built container classes for this?

Comment: @Ishtar: Below are the errors I get: 3 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Meredith\Desktop\Java410\linkedlist.java  [line: 25]
Error: ')' expected
File: C:\Users\Meredith\Desktop\Java410\linkedlist.java  [line: 25]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\Meredith\Desktop\Java410\linkedlist.java  [line: 25]
Error: ';' expected

Comment: @Scooter. Thanks. This is my first java class, sorry I do not understand your question but I don't think I am required to use Java pre-built container classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has a very simple solution.

You have to start from the first element of the list, put it in the `odd` list, and next to the `even`.

So all you have to is this,

1. Start from the head of the list, give to the `odd` function.
2. In the `odd` function store it in the `odd` list and call the `even` function with its next.
3. In the `even` function store it in the `even` list and call the `odd` function with its next.
4. Continue these steps until you reach null.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first programming so it is difficult for me.

Comment: You need further help? If so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors. Try this code:

```
public class OddEven {
  public List even(List L) {
    List toReturn = new ArrayList();

    //replace this line with code that takes all even
    toReturn.add(L.get(0));

    return toReturn;
  }

  public static void main(String []args) {
    OddEven o = new OddEven();
    List input = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);

    List even = o.even(input);

    System.out.println(even);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class linked_list {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        linked_list theApp = new linked_list();
        theApp.run();
    }

    public void run()
    {

        LinkedList<Object> theList = getListFromUser();
        System.out.println( theList );
        LinkedList<Object> oddList = odd(theList);
        System.out.println(oddList);
    }

    LinkedList<Object> even(LinkedList<Object> theList)
    {
        if (theList == null || theList.size() == 0 )
        {
            return null;
        }
        Integer a = (Integer) theList.removeFirst();
        return odd(theList);
    }

    LinkedList<Object> odd(LinkedList<Object> theList)
    {
        if (theList == null || theList.size() == 0 )
        {
            return null;
        }
        LinkedList<Object> temp = new LinkedList<Object>();
        Integer value = (Integer) theList.removeFirst();
        LinkedList<Object> temp2 = even(theList);
        if ( temp2 != null )
        {
           temp.addAll( temp2 );
        }
        temp.add(value);
        return temp;
    }

    LinkedList<Object> getListFromUser()
    {
        LinkedList<Object> temp = new LinkedList<Object>();
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int value = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter some integers for a list");
        System.out.println("Enter -1 when done");
        String integer;
        while (value != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter integer:");
            integer = user_input.next();
            value = Integer.parseInt(integer);
            if ( value != -1 )
            {
                temp.add( new Integer(value));
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

}
```

run:

```
Enter some integers for a list
Enter -1 when done
Enter integer:
1
Enter integer:
2
Enter integer:
3
Enter integer:
4
Enter integer:
5
Enter integer:
6
Enter integer:
7
Enter integer:
8
Enter integer:
9
Enter integer:
10
Enter integer:
-1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```